# Is it possible to write Time in hh:mm:ss+00 format in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime, datetime-format

I am using following code in R to calculate mean. My output has one column Time_sp which contains Date as well Time together written as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.

I want to add '+00' in time i.e., Time_sp column should be written as yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss+00. Is it possible to do it in R? Could anyone please help me in achieving it by modifying the given code.

Code:

```
abc <- merged %>%
  select(any_of(cn)) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  group_by(Time_sp = lubridate::floor_date(`Date/Time`, "5 mins")) %>% 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), ~ if(mean(is.na(.x)) > 0.5) NA else mean(.x, na.rm = 
                                                                               TRUE)))

write.csv(abc, paste0(dirlist[idx],"_mean.csv"), row.names = FALSE)
}
```

Comment: Sure, but it will be a character, no longer a datetime object. `format(Time_sp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00")`.

Comment: @zephryl Thank you for the response. Could you please tell me where I should put it in the code. I wrote in the line next to summarize as format(abc$Time_sp, "Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00") but it didn't make any changes in the output.

Comment: Any point after the floor_date, either inside the group_by or after. e.g. `group_by(Time_sp = lubridate::floor_date(`Date/Time`, "5 mins") %>% format( "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00")) %>% ...` or `mutate(Time_sp = format(Time_sp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S+00")) %>% ` in the following line.